# Only all VPN traffic by MAC except on specific port

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have a device on my network that can only get to the outside world via VPN. I use an OpenWRT router with two VLANs:

```
192.168.2.X: All devices including the one in question
192.168.3.X: Isolated server
```

I have this iptables setup like this to accomplish my goal. All this works fine.

```
#Whitelist server
iptables -I FORWARD 2 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -d 192.168.3.2 -j ACCEPT                                                                                                  
#Whitelist VPN connection
iptables -I FORWARD 3 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -d <PUBLIC VPN IP> -j ACCEPT
#Allow incoming OpenVPN connection
iptables -I FORWARD 4 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -d 10.1.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
#Block everything else
iptables -I FORWARD 5 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -j DROP
```

However I now have a service on this machine (Synology NAS) I would like to access from outside my network. Using the reverse proxy built into the GUI, I can access it just fine from the internal network. I get the "Page not found" error from the outside world. (Service runs on port 3000. Nginx reverse proxy works perfectly).

I ran `tcpdump` on the NAS to see what it looks like from internal vs. external network.

```
tcpdump -i eth0 host 192.168.2.10 and port 80 -n -s 0 -vvv
```

### Internal Network Example

Looks like good back and forth communication? Regardless pages load fine and I can interact like I would expect. Everything's good.

```
10:44:35.263734 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22203, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 483)
    192.168.2.10.80 > 192.168.2.229.46437: Flags [P.], cksum 0x8815 (incorrect -> 0x6d5b), seq 14449:14880, ack 2109, win 147, options [nop,nop,TS val 44852638 ecr 33125692], length 431
10:44:35.263971 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 22204, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 57)
    192.168.2.10.80 > 192.168.2.229.46437: Flags [P.], cksum 0x866b (incorrect -> 0x2281), seq 14880:14885, ack 2109, win 147, options [nop,nop,TS val 44852638 ecr 33125692], length 5
10:44:35.266280 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27016, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.2.229.46437 > 192.168.2.10.80: Flags [.], cksum 0x655d (correct), seq 2109, ack 14880, win 475, options [nop,nop,TS val 33125695 ecr 44852638], length 0
10:44:35.266351 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 27017, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    192.168.2.229.46437 > 192.168.2.10.80: Flags [.], cksum 0x6558 (correct), seq 2109, ack 14885, win 475, options [nop,nop,TS val 33125695 ecr 44852638], length 0
```

### External Network Example

The request makes it to the NAS, but the NAS appears to never respond (granted this is a small sample, but I never see the local IP respond to the public one)

```
10:47:44.549577 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 6216, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    <PUBLIC IP>.33821 > 192.168.2.10.80: Flags [S], cksum 0xd80e (correct), seq 1643727695, win 65535, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 33182471 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
10:47:44.549648 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 49426, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    <PUBLIC IP>.32694 > 192.168.2.10.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x2b29 (correct), seq 3430912533, win 65535, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 33182471 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
10:47:44.549726 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 17073, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    <PUBLIC IP>.53751 > 192.168.2.10.80: Flags [S], cksum 0x9568 (correct), seq 2421821881, win 65535, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 33182472 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
10:47:44.556677 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 50, id 45509, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    <PUBLIC IP>.62353 > 192.168.2.10.80: Flags [S], cksum 0xefcb (correct), seq 1128850125, win 65535, options [mss 1400,sackOK,TS val 33182472 ecr 0,nop,wscale 8], length 0
```

So I tried to create a rule that would only log if the firewall on router was blocking outgoing requests (NAS firewall has always been disabled). But nothing is being written to the log. So I am guessing my rule isn't setup right:

```
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -m mac --mac-source 00:11:22:33:44:55 -p tcp --sport 80 -j LOG --log-prefix "Blocked: " --log-level 7
```

Is it possible to force all outgoing WAN traffic through VPN except for the specific case when there is an http request? When an HTTP request comes in from the outside world and is forwarded to the NAS which hits the nginx reverse proxy, that will be allowed to respond.

Or is this the wrong approach all together?

Comment: Why do you want to do something by MAC address? MAC addresses are only significant or seen on the LAN where the host with a MAC address is connected, they are easily spoofed, and hosts do change or have NICs replaced. Using MAC addresses seems like a lot of work for very little gain, and requires a lot of maintenance, while leading you into a false sense of security.

Comment: I don't have to do it by MAC address. If there's a better approach to accomplish my goal, I am all for it.

Comment: The lone situation I am trying to solve is allowing HTTP requests that come in to the reverse proxy to respond outside the VPN. It appears right now those responses are being blocked. But I would still like the other rules to apply (IE: no other traffic out unless it's a whitelisted local machine or via the VPN.)